# How to add a column in clickhouse

Tags: alter-table, clickhouse

I have a table in clickhouse, say "my_table", which has replicates (my_table_rep1,...). And I need to add a column, of type float64, with default value (-1).

How should I do that?

I would prefer that the default are not actually added to existing entries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [documentation](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/alter/#column-manipulations) is pretty straight-forward:

> `ALTER TABLE [db].name [ON CLUSTER cluster] ADD COLUMN name [type] [default_expr] [AFTER name_after]`

Regarding that:

> I would prefer that the default are not actually added to existing entries.

There's also a statement in the docs:

> If you add a new column to a table but later change its default expression, the values used for old data will change (for data where values were not stored on the disk)

So, basically, you have to:

1. Add a column (without a default value, or with `DEFAULT 0`, or with something else - depends on what do you want to have in the existing entries)
2. Do `OPTIMIZE TABLE .. FINAL` to force Clickhouse to write the new data to the disk
3. Modify the column and set a DEFAULT -1 so only the new rows would be affected

An example:

```
 :) CREATE TABLE my_table (date Date DEFAULT today(), s String) ENGINE = MergeTree(date, (date), 8192);

 :) INSERT INTO my_table (s) VALUES ('1. foo');

 :) ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN f Float64;

 :) INSERT INTO my_table (s) VALUES ('2. bar');

 :) SELECT * FROM my_table;

┌───────date─┬─s──────┬─f─┐
│ 2018-04-20 │ 1. foo │ 0 │
│ 2018-04-20 │ 2. bar │ 0 │
└────────────┴────────┴───┘

 :) OPTIMIZE TABLE my_table PARTITION 201804 FINAL;

 :) ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY COLUMN f Float64 DEFAULT -1;

 :) INSERT INTO my_table (s) VALUES ('3. baz');

 :) SELECT * FROM my_table;

┌───────date─┬─s──────┬──f─┐
│ 2018-04-20 │ 3. baz │ -1 │
│ 2018-04-20 │ 1. foo │  0 │
│ 2018-04-20 │ 2. bar │  0 │
└────────────┴────────┴────┘
```

You really have to do `OPTIMIZE TABLE ... FINAL`, because if you won't do that, weird things will happen: https://gist.github.com/hatarist/5e7653808e59349c34d4589b2fc69b14

Comment: is there something like "ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXIST" ?

Comment: @crak checked the docs, seems like there's not; feel free to post a feature request! https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/new

Comment: The alter column command now supports checking if the column exists: `ADD COLUMN [IF NOT EXISTS] name [type] [default_expr] [codec] [AFTER name_after | FIRST]` ([docs](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/column#add-column))