# Clickhouse. Add a new column to the existing one

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Tell me how you can add a new column to the existing clickhouse table. At the same time, the data that was before should remain and this column should be filled with default data

Comment: just look at documentation - https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/column/#add-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a column in clickhouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944865/how-to-add-a-column-in-clickhouse)